# create folder and foldernames from list with terminal

Tags: terminal, command, line

I have a file called song_title.txt, plain text, and it has a list of 1800 songs. Now I want to make 1800 empty folders with the names of these songs listed in the text file.
How can I do that with the terminal in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy to do. You need just one command:

`xargs -I {} mkdir -p "{}" < song_title.txt`

Comment: thanks, it gives a little rror, because one of the song title has a '

Comment: xargs: unterminated quote

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a python script.

assume this is the content of your file **songs.txt**

```
a.mp3
b.mp3
c.mp3
d.mp3
e.mp3
f.mp3
```

**makefolder.py**

```
import sys
import os
try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(filename)
    songs = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
    os.makedirs('songs')
    for song in songs:
        os.makedirs('songs\\'+song[0].split('.')[0])
except Exception as e:
    print('Provide a file')
```

run this script as

`python makefolder.py songs.txt`

copy this **makefolder.py** and **songs.txt** in the same folder
,This script will create a folder songs and in that folder all other folder will be created